# How to get running application icons programatically in android

Tags: android

I am working on an application where I want to get running application icons in my app but I am unable to do this. I want to generate these icons in order.

Below I have the code.

```
 public void getAllICONS() {
    List<Drawable> icons = null;

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> processes = am1
            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (processes != null) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            // String pkgName = app.getPackageName();
            String packageName = processes.get(k).topActivity
                    .getPackageName();

            Drawable ico = null;
            try {
                String pName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm
                        .getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                appList.add("" + pName);
                ApplicationInfo a = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                ico = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        processes.get(k).topActivity.getPackageName());
                getPackageManager();


            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {


            }
            // icons.put(processes.get(k).topActivity.getPackageName(),ico);
            icons.add(ico);

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error at `icons.add(ico)` line.

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{booster.blue.winktechs.com.bluebooster/booster.blue.winktechs.com.bluebooster.BoostApps}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Comment: Can you update the question with the error from the comment above please?

Comment: actually now i am getting no error but its showing blank screen

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add items to a null list:

```
List<Drawable> icons = null;
```

Try instantiating an empty list first:

```
List<Drawable> icons = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
```

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{booster.blue.winktechs.com.bluebooster/booster.blue.winktechs.com.bluebooster.BoostApps}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Comment: now its giving this error on line: String packageName = processes.get(k).topActivity
                        .getPackageName();

Comment: can you please help me